# Espaçamento entre grids e imagem colada na card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

1. Como faço para dar um espaçamento entre o texto e o accordion:

[image: Espaçamento entre o texto e o accordion]

2. [image: Imagem Colada na card]

Segue o codigo: https://codepen.io/ludieverson/pen/vMqVXv

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />


<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
    <div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="accordion">
      <div class="card mb-3" >
          <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingOne"> 
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link "  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingTwo">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingFive">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSix">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSix" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSeven">
          <h5 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </button>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSeven" data-parent="#accordion">
          <div class="card-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>   
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://receita.economia.gov.br/acesso-rapido/legislacao/arquivos-e-imagens/legislacao-da-rfb/@@images/7fb7ecd6-00e6-460d-b3a4-f3f74df7687d.png" alt="person writing in a notebook beside by an iPad, laptop, printed photos, spectacles, and a cup of coffee on a saucer" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img src="https://receita.economia.gov.br/acesso-rapido/legislacao/arquivos-e-imagens/legislacao-da-rfb/@@images/7fb7ecd6-00e6-460d-b3a4-f3f74df7687d.png" alt="person writing in a notebook beside by an iPad, laptop, printed photos, spectacles, and a cup of coffee on a saucer" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">  
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body mb-3">
    This is some text within a card body.
  </div>  
</div>
    <div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="card-body">
    This is some text within a card body.
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Bootstrap a maneira mas prátia é usando os `utilities` de espaçamento vc pode conferir a lista completa aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Mas basicamente **M** é para `margin` e **P** é para `padding`, sendo que os valores vão de **1** a **5**, tipo `m-1` é uma `margem` pequena no elemento, e `p-5` seria um `padding` grande no elemento. Sendo que vc mode ainda aplicar apenas no `mt- = margin-top`, ou `mb- = margin-bottom`, o mesmo vale para o P. Se quiser os eixo **X** ou **Y** igual use `mx-` para a horizontal e `my-` para a vertical.

Então no seu caso eu apenas criei um espaçamento entre as `ROWs`, colocando `my-3` nelas e ficou conforme a imagem `<div class="row my-3">`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf
                moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod.
                Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda
                shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea
                proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim
                aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"
                                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingThree">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingFive">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseFive" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingFive" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSix">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix"
                                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseSix" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSix" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header p-0" id="headingSeven">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                                    data-target="#collapseSeven" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                                    Collapsible Group Item #1
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseSeven" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingSeven"
                            data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row my-3">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://receita.economia.gov.br/acesso-rapido/legislacao/arquivos-e-imagens/legislacao-da-rfb/@@images/7fb7ecd6-00e6-460d-b3a4-f3f74df7687d.png"
                    alt="person writing in a notebook beside by an iPad, laptop, printed photos, spectacles, and a cup of coffee on a saucer"
                    class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <img src="https://receita.economia.gov.br/acesso-rapido/legislacao/arquivos-e-imagens/legislacao-da-rfb/@@images/7fb7ecd6-00e6-460d-b3a4-f3f74df7687d.png"
                    alt="person writing in a notebook beside by an iPad, laptop, printed photos, spectacles, and a cup of coffee on a saucer"
                    class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body mb-3">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        This is some text within a card body.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```